# decode/unmarshal complex nested JSON data structure

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying process some JSON data that get returned from an API. However, it's not exactly a straightforward structure. It has a bunch of nested key/values. I would like to unmarshal it to a Go struct.

Is there simple way to this using go ?

```json
{
    "http_buffered_trace": {
     "request": {
      "headers": [
       {
        "key": ":authority",
        "value": "server.localhost:9443",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": ":path",
        "value": "/get_data",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": ":method",
        "value": "POST",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": ":scheme",
        "value": "https",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "user-agent",
        "value": "curl/8.1.2",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "content-length",
        "value": "1059",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "accept",
        "value": "application/json",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "authorization",
        "value": "auth data here ! ",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "content-type",
        "value": "application/json",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-forwarded-for",
        "value": "10.42.0.1",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-forwarded-host",
        "value": "server.localhost:9443",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-forwarded-port",
        "value": "9443",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-forwarded-proto",
        "value": "https",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-forwarded-server",
        "value": "traefik-64f55bb67d-6bbjl",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-real-ip",
        "value": "10.42.0.1",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "accept-encoding",
        "value": "gzip",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-apache-internal",
        "value": "true",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-request-id",
        "value": "995f0028-432e-499b-8bb9-c102834e150d",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-apache-expected-rq-timeout-ms",
        "value": "15000",
        "raw_value": ""
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "as_string": "Request body in here !",
       "truncated": false
      },
      "trailers": []
     },
     "response": {
      "headers": [
       {
        "key": ":status",
        "value": "200",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "content-type",
        "value": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "date",
        "value": "Wed, 01 Nov 2023 13:36:05 GMT",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "x-apache-upstream-service-time",
        "value": "4",
        "raw_value": ""
       },
       {
        "key": "server",
        "value": "envoy",
        "raw_value": ""
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "as_string": "Response body in here!",
       "truncated": false
      },
      "trailers": []
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Subjective, but that doesn’t look very complex. What did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: Start at the deepest element and build up.  I see something like `HeaderInfo`, `BodyInfo`; `Request` and `Response` actaully look like the same model; `HttpBufferedTrace` holds a request and response; and some top level model has a HttpBufferedTrace inside it.   Give it a try!  Keep in mind this kind of modeling is always more verbose than what you'd have in say python, where all typing and modeling is purely dynamic.

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: Volker - This is nice and great to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a simple way:

```golang
type Header struct {
    Key      string `json:"key"`
    Value    string `json:"value"`
    RawValue string `json:"raw_value"`
}

type Trailer = Header

type Body struct {
    Truncated bool   `json:"truncated"`
    AsString  string `json:"as_string"`
}

type Request struct {
    Headers  []Header  `json:"headers"`
    Body     Body      `json:"body"`
    Trailers []Trailer `json:"trailers"`
}

type Response = Request

type HttpBufferedTrace struct {
    HttpBufferedTrace struct {
        Request  Request  `json:"request"`
        Response Response `json:"response"`
    } `json:"http_buffered_trace"`
}

func main() {

    h := HttpBufferedTrace{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &h)

    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/VdMbckVg0bR

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get me started.